# Solar Module Voltage when bypass diode activate?

Tags: solar-cell, semiconductors, electrical, solar-energy

What happen to the voltage level when a solar module is shaded and one of its bypass diode is activated? Assuming this solar module has 3 bypass diodes.

I have been reading and can't seem to understand the theory. Should one bypass diode activate, I will assume the voltage should be 2/3 of the maximum Voc of a solar module?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If a group of cells can't keep its bypass diode reverse-biased, then by definition, the voltage across that group will be the \$V_f\$ (forward voltage drop) of the bypass diode.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Wish to clarify what is \$V_f\$ suppose to stand for?

Comment: It's the forward voltage drop of the bypass diode, since if it isn't reverse-biased any longer, it must be conducting current in the forward direction.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the clarification! :)